# How can I get a basic app that uses TcpClient to connect?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, port

I am trying to write a basic app that will read data off a port.  Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int port = 5600;
    string server = "MyDevLaptopName";
    TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
    tcpClient.Connect(server, port);

    NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    byte[] data = new byte[256];
    stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When I run the app above I get this error on the `tcpClient.Connect` command:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.90.91.19:5600

I am not sure why my computer will not respond (I am totally new to TCP ports and such).

**Is there a different way I need set this up to read data from a TCP port?**

Things I have checked:

- Windows Firewall is completely off.
- The IP address listed in the error is the internal IP address of my development machine (the machine I am trying to connect to).
- I do have Symantec Endpoint Protection, but it is controlled by Group Policy and it would be difficult for me to get turned off (but I can do it if need be).

**Update:**
There is a main frame server that is supposed to be sending TCP data to that port.  I do not control that machine/server or the method that it sends the data.  I am just trying to read the data that is sent to the port.

**Update II:**
The main frame is actually sending the data to a VM at my company.  I then use the technique found [here](http://www.rickwargo.com/2011/01/08/port-forwarding-port-mapping-on-windows-server-2008-r2/) to redirect that TCP traffic to the same port on my machine (where I hoped I could just read it off).

**Update III:**
The mainframe is the client and I need to be the server!.  Once I realized that I got things working.

Comment: Where's the code that you use to set up the "server" (i.e. the party that waits and listens for connections) on port 5600?

Comment: What kind of server is listening on that port? Can you use it from another client?

Comment: @Vaccano - You have not posted enough information.  You need to figure out the reason you are unable to connect to your server application.  If you do not have a server application then TCP is the wrong type of network connection you want to use.

Comment: @Jon - I have updated my question with the server info.  Basically it is a mainframe server here at my company.  The programer for that server told me that he would be sending the data via the TCP protocol on that port to my machine.  I assumed I could connect to the port and start reading the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try with another port number, are you in control of the server as well? if so try to follow these steps:

[C# Tutorial - Simple Threaded TCP Server](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server)

as you will see there you can listen in this way:

```
namespace TCPServerTutorial
{
  class Server
  {
    private TcpListener tcpListener;
    private Thread listenThread;

    public Server()
    {
      this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3000);
      this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
      this.listenThread.Start();
    }
  }
}
```

and you can connect in this way:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 3000);

client.Connect(serverEndPoint);

NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes("Hello Server!");

clientStream.Write(buffer, 0 , buffer.Length);
clientStream.Flush();
```

it seems trivial and it is, but port number is not a detail as some ports are not available or blocked by firewalls or so...

Comment: I can get the server to use a different port (though I am not in direct control of it).  I updated my question to indicate how the server is setup.

Comment: Maybe what I need to be coding is the server?  Maybe my mainframe is acting like a client and I need to be listening for it... I will try your server code and see if it works.

Comment: I was confused about server vs client (as I said I a new to TCP communications).  I needed to be the server and the mainframe was sending me data as a client.  Once I used the link you gave me to make a server it all started working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is the "client." You need a "server" running on the other machine that is listening for your incoming connection.